# Как отфильтровать строки, где после ":" есть маленькие и большие буквы?

Tags: delphi, строки

Мне нужно отфильтровать только те строки, где после символа “:” - есть набор букв и маленьких и больших.

То есть из строк:

```
ddd!ddd':'123456789
ddd!ddd':'ddddddddddd
ddd!ddd':'DDDDDD
ddd!ddd':'DDDaaaaDDD
```

мой код выдает:

```
ddd!ddd':'ddddddddddd
ddd!ddd':'DDDDDD
ddd!ddd':'DDDaaaaDDD
```

а должно быть так:

```
ddd!ddd':'DDDaaaaDDD
```

Вот мой, неправильный, код:

```
function Match(const S, LegalChars_L, LegalChars_R: string;
                      isCheck_L, isCheck_R: boolean;
                      Min_L, Max_L, Min_R, Max_R: integer ): boolean;
var pColon : integer;
  i, j, Len_R : integer;
begin
  Result := false;
  pColon := Pos(':',S);
  if pColon<1 then Exit;
  // если установлен фильтр на правую часть, проверим соответствие критериям
  if isCheck_R then begin
    Len_R := Length(S)-pColon;
    if Len_R<Min_R then Exit;
    if Len_R>Max_R then Exit;
    for i := pColon+1 to pColon+Len_R do
      if Pos(S[i], LegalChars_R )=0 then Exit;
  end;
  // все проверки прошли, значит, можно вернуть True
  Result := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.btStartClick(Sender: TObject);
const
Фильтры!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  constLetterUpper = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  constLetterLower = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

var
  f1,f2:TextFile;
  k, countRec : integer;
  s, s_R:string;
  check_R : boolean;
  scrFileSize : int64;
begin
..........
// сформируем строки с допустимыми символами
    s_R := '';
.........
Тут!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
s_R := s_R + constLetterUpper + constLetterLower

Вот тут!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 if Match(s, s_L, s_R, check_L, check_R, min_L, max_L, min_R, max_R) then begin
                Writeln(f2,s);
..........
```

Comment: Прочитал вопрос дальше .. ничего не понятно.

Comment: @Kromster, добавила максимально точную формулировку вопроса.

Comment: При чём тут сортировка? Может быть, "отфильтровать" или "выбрать" ?

Comment: @MBo, Да отфильтровать. Исправила вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если оставить проверку по Pos (проверка по диапазону выгоднее):

```
function Match(const S, LegalChars_L, LegalChars_R: string;
                      isCheck_L, isCheck_R: boolean;
                      Min_L, Max_L, Min_R, Max_R: integer ): boolean;
var pColon : integer;
  i, j, Len_R, Good, APos : integer;
begin
  Result := false;
  pColon := Pos(':',S);
  if pColon<1 then Exit;
  // если установлен фильтр на правую часть, проверим соответствие критериям
  Good := 0;
  if isCheck_R then begin
    Len_R := Length(S)-pColon;
    if Len_R<Min_R then Exit;
    if Len_R>Max_R then Exit;
    for i := pColon+1 to pColon+Len_R do
    begin
      Apos := Pos(S[i], LegalChars_R );  
      if APos = 0 then
        Exit
      else
        Good := Good or (1 + (APos - 1) div length(constLetterUpper));
    end;  
  end;
  // все проверки прошли, значит, можно вернуть True
  Result := Good = 3;
end;
```

Comment: Еще такой вопрос: провела все тексты с функцией и теперь выдает результат ddd!ddd':'DDDDDD и ddd!ddd':'DDDaaaaDDD. А по идее должен быть  результат только - ddd!ddd':'DDDaaaaDDD. То есть там где после ":" есть маленькие и большие буквы. Что еще нужно подправить в функции что бы она выдавала такой результат.

Comment: Надо убедиться, что цикл `for i := pColon+1 to pColon+Len_R` выполняется в правильных пределах. И строка `LegalChars_R` выглядит именно как `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

Comment: Убедилась. Но результат тот же...Это я не с претензией, просто не могу понять где прокол..

Comment: Добавил begin-end в цикл

Comment: Все, теперь заработал код. Получается за begin и end была погрешность.

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure TForm2.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  crlf = #13#10;
  a: array[0..9] of string =
    ('01:alpha'
    ,'02:ПоверкаСвязи'
    ,'03:ALARM'
    ,'04:ВНИМАНИЕ'
    ,'05:стоп '
    ,'06:остановка зарещена'
    ,'07:Не влезай - убьет'
    ,'08:ПИВО!'
    ,'09:Ученье - свет, а неученых тьма!'
    ,'10:Итог'
    );
var
  cnt : integer;
  res : string;
  sda : TStringDynArray;
begin
  res:='';
  for cnt:=0 to High(a) do
  begin
    sda:=SplitString(a[cnt],':');
    if Length(sda)<2 then Continue;
    if (AnsiLowerCase(sda[1])<>sda[1]) and
       (AnsiUpperCase(sda[1])<>sda[1]) then
      res:=res+crlf+a[cnt];
  end;
  ShowMessage(res)
end;
```